# Serving gzipped files using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, gzip, httpresponse, content-encoding

I'm trying to serve gzipped log files using Spring Boot REST.
Files are already gzipped, I don't need to gzip them.
Browser should unzip them and show plain text.

Based on the info I googled, I need two things to make it work:

- Set the following in request header: `'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'`
- Set the following in response header: `'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'`

Request is OK:

[image: Request Headers - Accept-Encoding]

Response is NOT - missing Content-Encoding header:
[image: Response Headers]

Here is my Java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download",
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> download(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    log.debug("REST request to get the filesystem resource");

    // hardcoded for testing purpose
    File f = new File("C:/file.log.gz");
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = null;
    HttpHeaders headers = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream);

        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");
        headers.add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/plain"))
        .body(inputStreamResource);
}
```

Is Spring removing this specific header from response?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that it is actually working :). I was using BrowserSync before to test it out and it's not working with BrowserSync for some reason.

Comment: Instead of an `InputStreamResource`, I have a `byte[]`, but otherwise I use the same code. Thanks.